# Error when videojs playlist is empty and I try to populate it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm using [videojs](https://videojs.com/) and [videojs-playlist](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist) and I allow the player to be updated dynamically. It's working well, until you remove all the playlist items and try to add one back in again. How can I prevent this from happening?

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: "this.player_ is null, can't access property "playlist" of it"

Comment: how are you removing all ? Is there some code you could share ?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an array of videos to `player.playlist(Array)`. You don't need to remove the old videos, this will replace them. Although you can clear the playlist with `player.playlist([])`

Comment: Thanks! This may sound basic but how can I reach `player` from page content generated after `player` was initiated or from inside a function? I just get a message that `player` doesn't exist and running `var vidplayer = videojs('id');` a second time seems to load the player again?

Comment: Finding myself having to run this every time I want to load new video content. `var oldPlayer = document.getElementById('id'); videojs(oldPlayer).dispose();`

Comment: `videojs('id')` a second time should return the player that already exists, so something's not right there. A [mcve] might help clear that up.